# Show one group image out of three based on cell input

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have the rotation working, it's just the hiding and unhiding of the three images that will not work. I have an "if" "else" loop for the three values that are autopopulated by a vlookup for either 90, 135, or 180 degrees. When I run the code, it seems to just pick one of the two images I tell to hide. What is really strange to me is it is not always the first group that gets hidden, sometimes it is the second. I don't understand how I could change the code to make it hide both images for each "if" scenario.

This is my code so far, only the if-else loop for hiding the groups is not working:

```
Sub Macro1()
    
    response = MsgBox("Are you sure the SP# is correct?", vbYesNo, "Angle Confirmation")
    If response = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
        Dim x As Integer
        x = Range("D23").Value
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 2")).Select
        Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementRotation x
        

        If Range("B24").Value = 90 Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group 13").Visible = False: ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group 25").Visible = False
        ElseIf Range("B24").Value = 135 Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group 5").Visible = False: ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group 25").Visible = False
        ElseIf Range("B24").Value = 180 Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group 5").Visible = False: ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group 13").Visible = False
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it doesn't **unhide** previously hidden shapes although B24 value would be correct. That's why your result looks "weird".

Try this code to hide *and* unhide the shapes based on the B24 value.
It first configures the visibility-value per shape.
And then sets the visibility per each shape based on the value of B24.
The advantage of the "configuration": if there are more groups you just add them to the array.

```vb
Public Sub hideGroupsBasedOnB24()

Dim arrConfig(2, 1) As Variant
'first dimension: group name, second dimension visible value
arrConfig(0, 0) = "Group 5": arrConfig(0, 1) = 90
arrConfig(1, 0) = "Group 13": arrConfig(1, 1) = 135
arrConfig(2, 0) = "Group 25": arrConfig(2, 1) = 180

Dim i As Long
With ActiveSheet
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrConfig, 1)
        .Shapes(arrConfig(i, 0)).Visible = .Range("B24").Value = arrConfig(i, 1)
    Next
End With

End Sub
```